# UIWebView sizeToFit() Smaller

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, size, sizetofit

It appears that using `sizeToFit()` on a `UIWebView` does not change the size to be smaller, only larger. This is some set-up code:

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 50.0, width: 800.0, height: 1200.0)

    webView = UIWebView()
    webView.frame = CGRect(x: 50.0, y: 50.0, width: 800.0, height: 1.0)
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    webView.delegate = self
    webView.scalesPageToFit = false
    webView.loadHTMLString("Test", baseURL: nil)

    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(webView)
}
```

This is my test code. It changes the size of the content to be VERY LARGE after 3 seconds, then VERY SMALL after another 3 seconds:

```
    dispatch_after_delay_main(3) {

        self.webView.loadHTMLString("Test Test Test Test ", baseURL: nil)
        // Much longer string abbreviated here

        dispatch_after_delay_main(3, block: {

            self.webView.loadHTMLString("Test", baseURL: nil)

        })
    }
```

This is called after the HTML is loaded. The goal is to change the size of the webView based on the size of its content. Note: I've done this with both .sizeToFit() and sizeThatFits() with the same size result.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

    webView.frame.size.height = 0.0 // Just in case
    webView.sizeToFit()

}
```

I've omitted the print statements at the end of `webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)` but they output the size growing, but not decreasing. In other words, it will grow, but then once `"Test"` is loaded, it does not decrease in size.

```
(800.0, 1.0)  // "Test" (before sizeToFit() called)
(800.0, 1976.0) // "Test Test .... Test "
(800.0, 1976.0) // "Test"
```

Answer (score 3):

do you need the webview embedded on a scrollView? I think not.

Try to change your HTML string to `"<div id='main-html'>Your text</div>"` and then on the `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate function you will do these things:

First, you get the content height with:

`var result : Float = NSString (webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('main-html').offsetHeight").floatValue`

Second, change the webview height with the result value.

And tries to change the height of webView.scrollView.contentSize using the same result value.

Finally, use the `webView.sizeToFit()`

Cheers

**EDIT:**

As you said, you can use:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

    webView.frame.size.height = 1.0 // Value needs to be > 0.0 and < of the current height
    webView.sizeToFit()

}
```

Comment: Do to the requirements at this time, yes, I do need to embed it. I have a very large header (UIView) with a webView below it. On small devices, the only way for the user to view the information on the webView is to have the header and webView embedded in the same scrollView.

Comment: This did, however, let me find the issue. The issue is in the fact that I was using webView.frame.size.height = 0.0 which, for some reason, doesn't allow the webView to resize smaller. If I use 1.0 (or I'm assuming anything other than 0.0) it works fine! :) If you'd like to edit your answer or submit a second one with that information, I will accept it

Comment: But do you just need use `webView.frame.size.height = 1.0` and your problem was solved?

Comment: As long as it is set to a value > 0 and < the current height, it seems to work